# Use regex for searching strings element in other string

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking for the best way to check if elements of strings are present in other string
I have two cases:

```
string1 = "BMW Serie 3 Touring 318d 143ch Business"
string2 = "bmw serie 3"
```

i would like to do:
if elements in string2 are in string1 so do something

but in the other case

```
string1 = "DS 7 crossback"
string2 = "ds7"
```

what i use in the first case, i cannot use for this case

I think that regex is the best way, but i dont know use match in if statement (Python) (of course i already used lower() to simplify the matching)

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Sounds like the [in](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details) operator would solve this problem

Comment: Can you add desired results for these cases? It isn't clear what you consider to be an "element", and whether "ds7" is or is not in "DS 7 crossback". Do spaces count? How about capitalization?

Comment: excuse me, what i meant is I want to match the example string "bmw serie 3" with for example the string "BMW Serie 3 Touring 318d 143ch Business" in other words, I want to retrieve all strings containing "bmw" "serie" and "3"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use regex, you can use a function  that is a part of the `strings` objects on `python` you can use `count` which give you the number of occurrences or just use `in` which will give you a `boolean` .

**option 1:**

```
string1 = "BMW Serie 3 Touring 318d 143ch Business"
string2 = "bmw serie 3"
if string1.count(string2) > 0:
    print("contain")
else:
    string1 = "DS 7 crossback"
    string2 = "ds7"
```

**option 2:**

```
string1 = "BMW Serie 3 Touring 318d 143ch Business"
string2 = "bmw serie 3"
if string2 in string1
    print("contain")
else:
    string1 = "DS 7 crossback"
    string2 = "ds7"
```

Comment: Thank you! this way helped me

Comment: glad to help (:

Answer (score 0):

you want to add some tolerance to substring search, removing the spaces and converting to lowercase:

```
>>> string1 = "DS 7 crossback"
>>> string2 = "ds7"
>>> string2 in string1.lower().replace(" ","")
True
```